# Select several max types for each datatype per distinct value in mysql

Tags: mysql, max, distinct

```
userid      data_type,          timespentaday
 1       League of Legends          500
 1       Hearthstone                1500
 1       Hearthstone                1400
 2       World of Warcraft          1200
 1       Dota 2                     100
 2       Final Fantasy              500
 1       Dota 2                     700
```

Given this data. I would like to query the most time each user has spent on every.

Output desired:

```
User    League Of Legends    Hearthstone   World of Warcraft     Dota 2    
 1           500                1500             0                  700
 2           0                  0                1200               0
```

Something along the lines of this is something I've tried

```
SELECT t1.* FROM user_info GROUP BY userid JOIN(
 SELECT(
         (SELECT max(timespentaday) where data_type='League of Legends'),
          (SELECT max(timespentaday) where data_type='Hearhstone'),
          (SELECT max(timespentaday) where data_type='Dota 2)'
FROM socialcount AS t2
) as t2
ON t1.userid = t2.userid
```

Comment: You are asking for an aggregate max (easy enough), then wanting the results as a pivot table. There are a few pivot examples on SO already (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table).

Comment: I would strongly suggest you think about making the pivot in your programming language of choice.  It is trivial to get the results you seek using only `MAX()` aggregate function along with `GROUP BY` on `userid` and `data_type` columns.  It is a much uglier query to get the data in pivot format like you propose, especially as number of games is, I assume, not fixed.

Comment: i didn't need to necessarily use MAX() it was just the approach i took.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically to do this you need the greatest n per group.. there is a good article on it but the gist is in mysql you have to use variables to even get close to this.. especially with doing a pivot on the table (a fake pivot since MySQL doesn't have native support for that).

```
SELECT userid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN data_type = "League of Legends" THEN timespentaday ELSE 0 END) as "League of Legends",
    MAX(CASE WHEN data_type = "Hearthstone" THEN timespentaday ELSE 0 END) as "Hearthstone",
    MAX(CASE WHEN data_type = "Dota 2" THEN timespentaday ELSE 0 END) as "Dota 2",
    MAX(CASE WHEN data_type = "World of Warcraft" THEN timespentaday ELSE 0 END) as "World of Warcraft",
    MAX(CASE WHEN data_type = "Final Fantasy" THEN timespentaday ELSE 0 END) as "Final Fantasy"
FROM
(   SELECT *, @A := if(@B = userid, if(@C = data_type, @A + 1, 1), 1) as count_to_use, @B := userid, @C := data_type
    FROM
    (   SELECT userid, timespentaday, data_type
        FROM gamers
        CROSS JOIN(SELECT @A := 0, @B := 0, @C := '') temp
        ORDER BY userid ASC, data_type ASC, timespentaday DESC
    ) t
    HAVING count_to_use = 1
)t1
GROUP BY userid
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/528c7/1)

### NOTE:

MySQL [**DOCS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html) is quite clear on warnings about using user defined variables:

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable
> and read the value within the same statement. You might get the
> results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of
> evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and
> may change based on the elements contained within a given statement;
> in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between
> releases of the MySQL Server. In SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ..., you might
> think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment
> second. However, changing the statement (for example, by adding a
> GROUP BY, HAVING, or ORDER BY clause) may cause MySQL to select an
> execution plan with a different order of evaluation.

Comment: You are a mysql legend. thanks! would appreciate the article link too

Comment: @Dap here is that [**ARTICLE LINK**](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to give you a query with the output format you desire, as implementing that pivot table is going to be a very ugly and poorly performing query, as well as something that is not scalable as the number of distinct games increases.

Instead, I will focus on how to query the data in the most straightforward manner and how to read it into a data structure that would be used by application logic to create the pivot view as desired.

First the query:

```
SELECT
  userid,
  data_type,
  MAX(timespentaday) AS max_timespent
FROM social_count
GROUP BY userid, data_type
```

This would give results like

```
userid    data_type               max_timespent
------    ---------               -------------
1         League of Legends       500
1         Hearthstone             1500
1         Dota 2                  700
2         World of Warcraft       1200
2         Final Fantasy           500
```

Now when reading the results out of the database, you just read it into a structure that is useful. I will use PHP as example language, but this should be pretty easily portable to any langauge

```
// will hold distinct list of all available games
$games_array = array();
// will hold user data from DB
$user_data = array();
while ($row = /* your database row fetch mechanism here */) {
    // update games array as necessary
    if (!in_array($row['data_type'], $games_array)) {
        // add this game to $games_array as it does not exist there yet
        $games_array[] = $row['data_type'];
    }
    // update users array
    $users[$row['userid']][$row['data_type']] = $row['max_timespent'];
}

// build pivot table
foreach($users as $id => $game_times) {
    // echo table row start
    // echo out user id in first element
    // then iterate through available games
    foreach($games_array as $game) {
        if(!empty($game_times[$game])) {
            // echo $game_times['game'] into table element
        } else {
            // echo 0 into table element
        }
    }
    // echo table row end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to build a query with a dynamic number of columns. You can do this query if you already know the game list, which I guess is not what you need. 
BUT you can always post-process your results with any programming language, so you only have to retrieve the data.

The SQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT
  userid AS User,
  data_type AS Game,
  max(timespentaday) AS TimeSpentADay
FROM
  my_table
GROUP BY
  userid
  data_type
```

Then iterate over the results to fill any interface you want

OR

If and only if you can't afford any post-processing of any kind, you can retrieve the list of games first THEN you can build a query like the query below. Please bear in mind that this query is a lot less maintainable than the previous (beside being more difficult to build) and can and will cause you a lot of pain later in debugging.

```
SELECT
  userid AS User,
  max(CASE 
    WHEN data_type = 'Hearthstone' THEN timespentaday 
    ELSE NULL 
  END) AS Hearthstone,
  max(CASE 
    WHEN data_type = 'League Of Legends' THEN timespentaday 
    ELSE NULL 
  END) AS `League Of Legends`,
  ...
FROM
  my_table
GROUP BY
  userid
```

The `CASE` contstruction is like an `if` in a procedural programming language, the following

```
CASE 
    WHEN data_type = 'League Of Legends' THEN timespentaday 
    ELSE NULL 
END
```

Is evaluated to the value of `timespentaday` if the game is League Of Legends, and to `NULL` otherwise. The `max` aggregator simply ignore the `NULL` values.

*Edit: added warning on the second query to explain the caveat of using a generated query thanks to Mike Brant's comment*

Comment: I honestly would just remove the pivot information from this answer as, though the OP might not realize this now, that is the only reasonable approach to querying this data.